# Софт для проектирования контейнерной сети

Tags: проектирование, контейнеры

Ищу что-нибудь приличное для создания схемы контейнерной сети. Наверное, для примера можно привести как dbdesigner для проектирования логической модели бд. А то поднадоело пилить схемы на drawio.

Пример схемы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Подпись каждой стрелки - порт
- Out: <PORT> - порт, который отдает контейнер. Так, например, для доступа к интерфейсу кибаны необходимо подключится к 5601 порту контейнера кибаны. Его и отдаем.

Comment: От Вашей идеи веет свежим и благородным безумием. Это я в хорошем смысле :-) Действительно, почему бы и нет: накидал разных штук, связал их связамя и на выходк - хочешь - докер композ, хочешь - кубернетисовый ямл. А можно к вопросу добавить пример схемы, просто чтобы понять уровень сложности той сети, котрая проектируется?

Comment: @S.H. да, конечно. (Я бы назвал это примером на коленке). Схема получилась дурная и непонятная. Что-то взял от DFD, что-то от IDEF0, но это не то совершенно....